# Java, Map same object to different objects

Tags: java, dozer, mapper, orika

I have a list of `Car`'s, I want to map them to different specific `Car`'s like - `FordCar`, `HondaCar`, `VolkswagenCar`... base on value of `maker` attribute of `Car`, that is `Car.maker`

Can Dozer, MapStruct do this?
Or is there any framework in Java which can do this?

Comment: Why Dozer? There is a standard Java type `Map`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: You can give MapStruct a try. 
http://mapstruct.org/

Comment: @ToanLu thanks for your quick response, but here my problem is little different, for example say - I have a list of `Car`s, I want to map them to `FordCar`, `HondaCar`, `VolkswagenCar`... base on value of `maker` attribute of `Car`, that is `Car.maker`

Comment: @ToanLu: Yor example in the original question shows completely different case. Adjust your example to get better answers.

Comment: @mentallurg did you mean CS Sardar?

Comment: the person who is giving -1 to the question, please be informed, i have done my home works, i have read entire documents of MapStruct, but still can not find anything helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any extra requirement, you could do this simply using Java-8.

```
Map<String, Supplier<Car>> creators = new HashMap(){{
  put("honda", ()-> new HondaCar());
  put("ford", ()-> new FordCar());
}}

listOfCars.map(Car::getMaker).map(maker -> creators.get(maker).get())
```

Answer (score 0):

After long finding, conclusion - as of now MapStruct does not support it. That is mapping of Map<> entries.
I did a round about - map a Map<> to a Map<> and flatten it using JackSon property `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter`

Answer (score -1):

Orika, remap, Selma, MapStruct.

To get your specific mapping, implement it in the mapper.

Comment: I have red example of those frameworks, but they are talking about `1-to-1` mapping, not `1-to-many` mapping, can you please read once my modified explanations